# wordpress automatic update does not run

Tags: plugin-development, actions, updates, automatic-updates

Hey Im creating automatic update plugin for wordpress and i have added following code using `add_action('init'`

```
    add_filter( 'allow_major_auto_core_updates', '__return_true', 1 );
    add_filter( 'allow_minor_auto_core_updates', '__return_true', 1 );
    add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true', 1 );
    add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_true', 1 );
```

before adding this code i have 4 updates for plugins/themes . after added this no updates happened for last 1 hour ! I have a doubt that when automatic updates runs ? i searched on internet and came to conclusion on how WordPress does automatic updates for new releases via `wp-cron`.

but what about existing updates i have(4 updates i have now)?
when this will be done automatically? Do you have any idea how this happen and also i have a doubt that how do i check my plugin whether it is working or not? should i wait for new release every time? Im totally confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got solution :
There are setting when `cron` job at `wp-option` table. my next auto update scheduled for next day. I did tweak (changed yesterday's time) so cron ran when i run the page now and updates done.